# Number Patterns In Java

Tags: java, numbers

Hello I wrote this code to print this form

```
public class Pattern{

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print(j+" ");                              
            }

            for(int k=i-1;k>=1;k--){
                System.out.print(k+" ");
            }        

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

1

2 3 2

3 4 5 4 3

4 5 6 7 6 5 4

5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5

---

But it was shown output

1

1 2 1

1 2 3 2 1

1 2 3 4 3 2 1

1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

please guide me

Comment: The answer does not want just a guide
I need him please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to introduce one more variable for printing this pattern. here I've named that variable `m`. And you also have to make some changes to your internal two `for` loops as following:

```
  int m=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        for(int j=m;j<=i+m-1;j++){
            System.out.print(j+" ");                              
        }

        for(int k=i+m-3;k>=m-1;k--){
            System.out.print(k+1+" ");
        }        

        System.out.println();
        m++;
    }
```

**Output**

```
1 
2 3 2 
3 4 5 4 3 
4 5 6 7 6 5 4 
5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        int j=0; int val = i + 2;
        for(j=1; j < i ; j++){
            System.out.print(i + j -1+ " ");
        }
        System.out.print(i + j -1 + " ");
        for(j=i-1; j >= 1 ; j--){
            System.out.print(i + j -1 +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do want you want. The outer loop keeps track of the starting number for each line, which also defines the highest number on that line (2*i-1). The first inner loop than prints the numbers from the starting number of the line to the highest number. The second inner loop finally prints the numbers from the highest number back to the number the line started with.

```
for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j <= i-1) {
        System.out.print(i+j++);
    }
    while (j >= 1) {
        System.out.print(i+--j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```